# WP auto comment approve for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, comments, action

I have added the action for auto approve comments for my `xyz` custom post. But its not working when added the condition `if($post_type =='course')`. I have tried with also filter. But its not working. How can i solve that?

**Action:**

```
global $post_type;
if($post_type =='xyz'){
    function action_pre_comment_approved( $array, $int, $int ) { 

    }; 
add_action( 'pre_comment_approved', 'action_pre_comment_approved', 10, 3 ); 
}
```

**Filter:**

```
global $post_type;
if($post_type =='xyz'){
    function filter_pre_comment_approved( $approved, $commentdata ) { 

        return $approved; 
    }; 
    add_filter( 'pre_comment_approved', 'filter_pre_comment_approved', 10, 2 ); 
}
```

Comment: why cant you tick the option for auto approve in wp-admin ->discussion?

Comment: @charankumar because dashboard option control need for blog post comment. I want my own custom post type comment auto approve without dashboard controlled system. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Wordpress internal function which actually sets comment status to approved is seen nowhere in your code:

```
wp_set_comment_status( $comment_id, $comment_status )
```

Your code might be firing when it sees comment posted but as there is no function which can modify comment status present, the comment does not get approved.
In my opinion, when this function is used, you might need only one from 'action' or 'filter' to modify the comment status. Let us know the result if you try this out. 
[Visit Page from Wordpress Codex for more details on this function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_comment_status)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
function filter_pre_comment_approved( $approved, $commentdata ) {   
    global $post_type;
    if($post_type =='xyz'){
        return $approved; 
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_comment_approved', 'filter_pre_comment_approved', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: you need to add the condition inside function

Comment: thanks! its working but its also auto approved blog post comment. I want auto approve only for `xyz` custom post. Blog post need to usually controlled by WP default dashboard Settings->Discussion. Thanks!

Comment: I have used your updated code. Now custom post and blog post both are not working. What should I do now? Thanks! [plugin](https://gist.github.com/nvourva/aa47735e9ac2241403066c756ae8f94a)

Comment: can you print this value `$approved` and share me the screenshot?

Comment: I have added `print($approved); var_dump($approved);` below of `return $approved; ` but can't see any result on frontend.

Comment: add some additional text or echo "<pre>";

Comment: Sorry, I can't see any output result on frontend.

Comment: can you share the site url?

Comment: check like this `function filter_pre_comment_approved( $approved, $commentdata ) {   
    global $post_type;
    echo "<pre>==>";
    echo $approved;
    echo "</pre>";
    if($post_type =='xyz'){
        return $approved; 
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_comment_approved', 'filter_pre_comment_approved', 10, 2 );`

Comment: you can see this `<pre>==>` in frontend?

Comment: I can't saw anything in fronted. But my problem has solved. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is still wondering, this works:

```
function filter_pre_comment_approved( $approved, $commentdata ) {   
    $post_type = get_post_type($commentdata['comment_post_ID']);
    if($post_type == 'xyz'){
        $approved = true;
    } 

    return $approved;
}
add_filter( 'pre_comment_approved', 'filter_pre_comment_approved', 10, 2 );
```